# htaccess get value with spaces

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
example.com/search/search+something I want to like this search but its not work
```

example.com/search/.htaccess

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /search/

RewriteRule ^(\w+)(?:/[^/]+)?/?$ load.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/[^/]+/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?q=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

How to fix it... if i type like this `example.com/search/songs` its work. but after `songs` add something with spaces or (+) not work and show 404 page.. `ex :(example.com/search/songs+video)`

Comment: friend this is not a redirect...

Comment: i want to get value only

Comment: friend help me.. if u can post answer for that... all codes plzz

Comment: May be check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867514/using-spaces-in-url-and-htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `\w` to `[^/]` so that you can match spaces but not slashes. Encoded spaces in the URI get decoded before getting matched by patterns in rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/[^/]+)?/?$ load.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You may also want to add a `NE` flag in the square brackets if the string ends up with `%20` in the `load.php` script.

Comment: friend its work. but last one not work like this.. example.com/search/video+songs/page/2

Comment: if u can edit your answer and plz put full answer for my last one

Comment: @user3501407 for `example.com/search/video+songs/page/2` you need to add a "page": `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?q=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]`