# How to allow space in url rewriting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting, query-string

I have implement rewrite rule for two query string

```
<match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)"/>
```

How can I allowed spaces in query string through URL rewrite.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867514/using-spaces-in-url-and-htaccess